# Don't understand Django's ORM - Models

Tags: python, django

As I'm having some spare time these days I decided that it would be nice to learn a new language. So I picked python because of its popularity and because I got interested in Django.

Some hours later, despite all syntax related difficulties derived from a new language, I manage to make a simple backend logic design (what my "app" should do). The next step now was to introduce my code to Django to finally make that logic "real" in a way and to also learn some HTML, CSS in the process.

After following Django's official tutorial I felt I learned enough to get my project started.

Before I start talking about Django's ORM I want to say that, from what I've seen and learned in the tutorials, I totally enjoyed all Django's web-related utilities (views, paths, templates). They seem, at least for now, really easy to learn and simple to use.

Now about the ORM.

First of all, I feel that it is necessary to clarify that it's the second ORM I use in my life; the first one I used was Java's JPA in one of my courses to learn about them.

From what I've learned using JPA, I feel that one of the main objectives of an ORM is to try not to make me modify all the code I've already written. In that way the development of an app would be easy:

1. st - design the backend code (case uses, the model of the app: classes, objects, functions).
2. nd - map that model to a relational one so that it could be persisted in a database.
3. rd - create views and all the front end stuff.

The first problem I met with Django's ORM was the fact that there is not a OneToMany relationship, so if in my starting code I had:

```
    class Question:
       pass

    class Exam:
        __init__(self, questions):
            self.questions = questions     # list of questions
```

I had to change it to:

```
    class Question:
       exam = models.ForeignKey('Exam', on_delete=models.CASACADE, related_name='questions', ...)

    class Exam:
       pass
```

Maybe I'm not really understanding Django "models", after all, I'm just a newbie. But I find this terrible. What if my class 'Exam' had methods that rely on using such a question list to do its work. I've seen that I could access it using `an_exam.questions.all()` but I feel this is bad because for example:

1. My IDE (PyCharm), at least, doesn't recognize these attributes; I'm guessing they are defined at runtime. This can lead to runtime errors in case I've many of these attributes being used in my classes and I mess up their names.
2. Add that to the fact that I could have my class (Exam) and the one that defines the ForeignKey (Question) in separate files. So I wouldn't be able to know easily what attributes my class has (more errors).
3. Finally, I guess that `an_exam.questions.all()` returns all the questions related to the given exam that are **saved** in the database. What about those that are not yet?

Another problem I encountered was that I should not override the `__init__` method. This would make me change all the occurrences of the initialization of my classes. Of course I can get around it, with, as I saw somewhere on the internet, defining a class_method so that `an_exam = Exam.new_exam()`; but why would Django make me do this?

Merging both problems: What about a class that to initialize takes a list of elements to which it is related by a OneToMany relation? Take 'Exam' for example, no only I would appeal to the shady idea of creating an initializing method, but also I would have to create several setting methods extra that make use of the autogenerated 'questions' attribute (and other attributes if exist) to correctly set the attribute:

```
class Question:
    exam = models.ForeignKey('Exam', on_delete=models.CASACADE, related_name='questions', ...)

class Exam:
    @classmethod
    def new_exam(cls, questions):
        exam = Exam()
        exam.set_questions(questions)
        return exam

    def set_questions(questions):
        for q in questions:
            q.exam = self
            q.save()
            # something like this
```

To finish I want to say that I know that I'm a complete newbie to Django and python itself. That's why I'm certain that I must be mistaken with all that I've said and more; I'm witting this with the objective that someone would point out my mistakes.

I feel that I'm mistaken about what Django models really mean. I didn't think about them much, I assumed that they referred to my actual application logical / back-end design model: how responsibilities are distributed, the requirements to be satisfied and the logic behind it.

I'm looking forward to someone who would illuminate me the path out of this overwhelming and disappointing feeling. Thanks for reading till the end :)

Comment: As for the first issue regarding PyCharm not picking up the auto-generated reverse relationships between models. This is something that is available in the professional edition but not the community edition

Comment: That's cool. But still, I feel that it is a little wrong to use them all over my code and refactor my code around them.

Comment: But what about the reverse? If you defined a "one-to-many" field on a model then you would implicitly create a foreign key on the related model

Comment: Django is designed with the philosophy of most data entry being done via user input. Your example of creating an instance of an `Exam` class with the members of the `question` relationship passed to it has a Django paradigm - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: not a huge fan of ORMs myself.  but your objections seem relatively limited in weight compared to the massive benefit that comes from Django's admin.  and, no, you would not typically have Exam and Question in different files, Python doesnt  follow Java's 1-class <=> 1-file paradigm, they would normally be expected to be in **models.py** if on same app and might very well break things if not.  Your question not necessarily a bad question to have but I am not at all sure how it fits in SO's *show me how to fix this error* intent.

Comment: If you come from Java, best to approach Python without looking back too much how things were done in Java, that's bound to frustrate you.  getters and setters for example are another massive point of divergence, as well as private and public attribute qualifiers.  having said that, welcome to !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take on models/ORM and why they are such a pleasure: Without them, there's a ton of work to create and maintain SQL (queries) and DDL (to create/update database tables). With the ORM, you cut all of that work out: they define the database tables (each as a model) and convert PK, FK relationships to object relationships. Examples are better than abstract descriptions, so here's an example of a very simple model in one of my apps:

```
class LimitType(models.Model):
    limit = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False, blank=True)
    departments = models.ManyToManyField(Department, blank=True, related_name='departmental_limits')
    createTimestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updateTimestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    createdById = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.PROTECT, unique=False, null=False)
    modifiedById = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.PROTECT, unique=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.limit

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["limit"]
```

Notice how this class is a Model class, not some generic class. Models should represent what's in the database--their "job" is to encapsulate the **relational** database  tables as objects. Also notice the pattern of thinking here, each field in this LimitType class is a direct correlate to columns in a (swappable/pluggable) database (a feat not feasible without an ORM layer or some such equivalent).

With a model instantiated, one can use all of python's syntactical conventions to collect, select, update, and order related objects:

```
For type in LimitType.objects.all():
  type.do_something()
```

Moreover, it is easy to traverse OneToMany (and ManyToMany) relationships:

```
for type in LimitType.objects.all():
    print(type.departments.count())
```

These snippets are the kind code that could be found in other classes or in the views of a Django project.

Naturally, this is only the tip of the iceberg; there are so many convenient features in Django's and SQLAlchemy's ORM that it is worth learning both. Perhaps your confusion/frustration stems from conflating the model class with other kinds of classes. Keep them separate (put them in models.py file) and think of them as (1) your means of persistence and (2) the blueprint for your applications structural relationships.

Comment: Yes! I think my confusion is there. So you're saying that I should try not to think in the pure OOP that Java taught me. I should design my "model classes" with the main purpose of persisting my data and from there improve them to achieve the functionalities I need to accomplish; using functions methods or even other "kind of classes". I'm thinking it would be a good idea to first do my basic plane model classes and then after anything else start thinking about the views of the app, to see what is the logic I really need to cover, and finally adding that logic. Did I understand?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you've got it now.  To elaborate: first define the data in the database, then polish the model by adding functions (and properties!). A super simple example, might be a method called `full_name` that returns two fields joined together: `self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name`.